How to clear selection in a CollectionView by clicking OK in a DisplayAlert?
**Hello everybody. I´m trying to clear selection in a CollectionView after clicking "OK" in a DisplayAlert but I haven´t be able to achieve it. Here´s my original code (regci is my database):
**
 private  void collectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var itemSelected = e.CurrentSelection[0] as regci;
            if (itemSelected != null)
               DisplayAlert($"{itemSelected.Cliente} {"-"} {itemSelected.Equipo}",
               Environment.NewLine + $"{"Rpm del motor: "}{itemSelected.Motor} {" rpm"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
               $"{"Diámetro de polea motriz: "}{itemSelected.Motriz} {" in"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
               $"{"Diámetro de polea conducida: "}{itemSelected.Condu} {" in"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
               $"{"Amplitud: "}{itemSelected.Amp} {" in"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
               $"{"Frecuencia del sistema: "}{itemSelected.Frec}{" rpm"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
               $"{"Fuerza G: "}{itemSelected.FG}" + Environment.NewLine, "OK", "-")
   
            return;

        }```





**Then I changed my code to this: **

   

    private async void collectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemSelected = e.CurrentSelection[0] as regci;
        var res = await DisplayAlert($"{itemSelected.Cliente} {"-"} {itemSelected.Equipo}",
           Environment.NewLine + $"{"Rpm del motor: "}{itemSelected.Motor} {" rpm"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
           $"{"Diámetro de polea motriz: "}{itemSelected.Motriz} {" in"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
           $"{"Diámetro de polea conducida: "}{itemSelected.Condu} {" in"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
           $"{"Amplitud: "}{itemSelected.Amp} {" in"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
           $"{"Frecuencia del sistema: "}{itemSelected.Frec}{" rpm"}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
           $"{"Fuerza G: "}{itemSelected.FG}" + Environment.NewLine, "OK", "-");
        if (res == true)
        {
            collectionView.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }
       
    }


**But when I click on "OK" the message** *"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"* **shows up**

**Hope someone can help me **


try setting SelectedItems = null

Hi Jason,
I already tried that way but the same message appears. ("Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index")
